# How to IF not post dont UPDATE

Tags: php

I have the following normal form :

**FORM:**

```
                <div id="ajaXmsg"></div>
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="#" class="formee" id="useredit"/>
<input type="hidden" name="p" id="p" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="retype" id="retype" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="oldpass" id="oldpass" value="">
<?php $n->generateFormFields(); ?>
<table style="margin:0 auto;width:100%">
        <tr>

            <td style="font-weight:bold;">שינוי שם משתמש (נוכחי <span style="color:blue;"><?php echo $user['username']; ?></span>) ל - </td>
            <td>
                <input style="height:30px;width:250px;padding:0;line-height:30px;" type="text" id="uname" name="uname" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>" class="inplaceError" /><span class="clear" id="uname_error"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;">שינוי שם פרטי (נוכחי <span style="color:blue;"><?php echo $user['user_fname']; ?></span>) ל - </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="fname" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $user['user_fname']; ?>" name="fname" class="inplaceError" style="height:30px;width:250px;padding:0;line-height:30px;" /><span class="clear" id="fname_error"></span></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;">
שינוי שם משפחה(נוכחי <span style="color:blue;"><?php echo $user['user_lname']; ?></span>) ל - </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="lname" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $user['user_lname']; ?>" name="fname" class="inplaceError" style="height:30px;width:250px;padding:0;line-height:30px;" /><span class="clear" id="lname_error"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;">שינוי דוא"ל (נוכחי <span style="color:blue;"><?php echo $user['useremail']; ?></span>) ל - </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="email" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $user['useremail']; ?>" name="email" class="inplaceError" style="height:30px;width:250px;padding:0;line-height:30px;" /> <span class="clear" id="email_error"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;">שינוי סיסמא:</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="password"  name="password" style="height:30px;width:250px;padding:0;"/><span style="color:black;font-weight:bold;" class="inplaceError"> *הקש שנית: </span><input type="password" id="newpass"  onclick="this.value='';" name="newpass" class="inplaceError" style="height:30px;width:250px;padding:0;line-height:30px;"/><span class="clear" id="password_error"></span><span class="clear" id="newpass_error"></span></td>
        </tr>
<tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;">*סיסמא נוכחית:</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="oldpassinp" name="oldpassinp" class="inplaceError" style="height:30px;width:250px;padding:0;line-height:30px;"/> 
            <span class="clear" id="oldpassinp_error" ></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="#" id="submitedit" onClick="return false;" style="text-decoration:none;"><div class="editbut">עדכן</div></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
        if ($update_stmt = $func->mysqli->prepare(

        "UPDATE users SET 
           username = ?,
           useremail = ?,
           user_fname = ?,
           user_lname = ?,
           timestamp = ?,
           password = ?, 
           salt = ? 
           WHERE userid = '".$user_data['userid']."'"

        ))
        {

        $update_stmt->bind_param('sssssss',$uname, $useremail,$user_fname,$user_lname,$timestamp, $password, $random_salt);
        // Execute the prepared query.
        $update_stmt->execute();
            $return = array('form' => true,'key' => $json['2'], 'nonce' => $json['1']);
             header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
             echo json_encode($return);

        }
        else
        {
               $return = array('form' => false,'key' => $json['2'], 'nonce' => $json['1']);
                header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
               echo json_encode($return);

        }
```

Now i send via ajax, all working perfect execpt one thing:

even if the field(post) is empty it will update the field to empty, which is not good, i need to keep the same field without update ,**i mean dont update at all the specific column if is empty**, how i do it ?

EG:

if post username is empty , dont update at all username column.

Thanks in advance,more code will added if needed.

**EDIT 1 :**

```
 username=(CASE username WHEN '".empty($_POST['uname'])."' THEN username ELSE ? END),
```

This what u mean ?

Comment: use `if(isset($_POST) && $_POST !='') { your update code here }`.....

Comment: i have it, its not the problem , the problem is inside the update function, which will update to '' (empty) even if not posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql [`case`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) in your query like.

```
UPDATE tablename
   SET column1 = CASE WHEN  phppostvalue = '' THEN column1 ELSE ? END
WHERE someconditions
```

you can have multiple conditions in your query like,

```
UPDATE tablename
   SET column1 = CASE WHEN  phppostvalue = '' THEN column1 ELSE ? END,
   SET column1 = CASE WHEN  phppostvalue = '' THEN column1 ELSE ? END,
   SET column1 = CASE WHEN  phppostvalue = '' THEN column1 ELSE ? END
WHERE someconditions
```

Comment: Hi ,i am not that strong with mysql Query's i'v edit my question, could u look if that what u mean ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP :

```
$buildQuery = 'UPDATE user SET ';
foreach($_POST as $key => $values) {
    if($values != '') {
        $buildQuery .= "{$key} = ? ";
        // Bind values
        $paramList  .= "{$values},";
    }
}
$buildQuery .= "WHERE userid = '".$user_data['userid']."'";
//remove last comma
trim($paramList, ',');
```

I don't have test this but something like this should do the trick. For instance I don't have check for undefined variables...